# Parser for Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, parsing

For my current project I need a SQL parser that parses Oracle SQL statements.
Currently I've been using jsqlparser, which worked well for simple queries. But when specific functions occur (e.g. cast() or (+)) the parser fails.

Can anyone suggest a parser that is fully compliant to Oracle SQL?

Best,
Will

Comment: what exactly do you want to get out of this parser?

Comment: basically its enough if i get the AST of the statement, as I've already wrote my visitor for the jsqlparser, which I will need to adapt to the new parser, if there is any better.

Comment: AST Automatic Statement Tuning ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered [General SQL Parser](http://www.sqlparser.com/)? I don't have any experience with it myself but browsing their website it has potential. Personally I have rolled my own built on the parser in Eclipse Data Tools Platform (sorry I can't share, it's proprietary), but now I will have to evaluate the one I linked above because it claims to have more coverage of Oracle SQL than my parser does.

Comment: Yeah I also discovered their website and already tried parsing some queries using this parser. However their trial version only allows parsing 2000 characters so I can't fully test and evaluate whether it will be worth it to buy it. So I was thinking maybe someone knows some good alternatives or has some experience to share :)

Comment: I eventually decided to get the license for this parser. Seems fine so far, but already discovered a bug in its grammar.

Comment: It will be interesting to see how responsive they are to fixing the bug.

Comment: They are not very responsive, the first guy contacted me after one week and provided me with a link to download "improved" version of the parser. Tried it again and did not solve my problem. Contacted him again, and haven't gotten any response for over 6 weeks now..

Answer (score 12):

The ANTLR ([v3](http://www.antlr3.org/), [v4](http://www.antlr.org/)) parser generator has had a number of Oracle SQL and PL/SQL grammars written for it; see the [grammar list](http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/list.html) (v3) for details. Of those:

- I've used Andrey Kharitonkin's *"Oracle PL/SQL Grammar for ANTLR v3"*; from memory it supported most SQL and PL/SQL syntax from the 8i era, with a few bits and pieces that appeared in 9i and 10g
- Patrick Higgins' *"PL/SQL"* grammar is newer and claims to support most 11g syntax, but it appears to just swallow most DML statements - not too useful if you're specifically interested in SQL

Comment: "Grammar list" link is broken

Comment: Updated. Looks like things got moved around after the ANTLR 4 release.

Answer (score 7):

After working the same issue, I managed to get a SQL parser working:

- Download Oracle SQL Developer from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html.
- Oracle SQL developer contains a set jars and some of the APIs are documented as part of Oracle Fusion Middleware Java API Reference for Oracle Extension SDK (a link to the javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/jdev/ESDKJ/index.html?oracle/javatools/db/sql/class-use/SQLQueryBuilder.SQLQueryObjectSet.html).
- One of the available classes is *oracle.javatools.db.sql.SQLQueryBuilder*.

My code looks like this:

```java
import oracle.jdeveloper.db.DatabaseConnections;
import oracle.javatools.db.sql.SQLQueryBuilder;
import oracle.javatools.db.Database;
...
// load the database connections
// this is specific to Oracle SQL developer
DatabaseConnections connections = DatabaseConnections.getPrivateInstance(
    (new File("src/test/resources/connection.xml")).toURI().toURL(),
    "somePassword");
// get the one we are interested in
Database database = connections.getDatabase("the-name-of-a-sqldeveloper-connection");
SQLQueryBuilder queryBuilder = SQLQueryBuilderFactory.createBuilder(
      database, new Schema("OPTIONAL_SCHEMA"), "select * from some_table");
```

The challenges to get this working are:

- Getting the Oracle SQL Developer is a challenge. To do this, you will need to hack the files Oracle SQL Developer creates to persist those connections; the *connection.xml* in the above example looks something like this:

```xml
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<References xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/jndi">
   <Reference name="the-name-of-a-sqldeveloper-connection"     className="oracle.jdeveloper.db.adapter.DatabaseProvider" xmlns="">
      <Factory      className="oracle.jdevimpl.db.adapter.DatabaseProviderFactory1212"/>
  <RefAddresses>
     <StringRefAddr addrType="password">
        <Contents>HSx10FtlsPc=</Contents>
     </StringRefAddr>
     <StringRefAddr addrType="oraDriverType">
        <Contents>thin</Contents>
     </StringRefAddr>
...
```

To get such a file you will need to dig into the folder where Oracle SQL Developer settings are stored and just copy-paste that content into your own file.

- Next challenge is to define the database password. That is encrypted but this post (https://community.oracle.com/message/12359081) should be very helpful - just check the answer at the end of the post.

Now, assuming you managed to get this far here are the problems and the points where I got disappointed by the end solution:

- The API in the builder is decent but parsing will **perform a query execution** (and this might be a big issue - in my case I needed the parsing to be fast).
- The API is **not officially public**. Without being able to quote here the precise wording, I got an Oracle answer that stated there is no officially supported Oracle parser (the alluded reason was that this is a very valuable technology that will not be sold or licensed).
- While this is more of a hack than a solution, I realized that it might be useful for some cases (not mine). I consider that using it in real life scenarios might be highly risky from both technical and legal perspectives.

The reason I posted this answer is to drive community attention to the fact that having an **Oracle SQL parser is perfectly feasible** and maybe one day Oracle will consider exposing the parser as a competitive advantage (I am sure there are users out there that would happily pay some fees to get a license).

Comment: what they have asked and what you have replied ?

Answer (score 6):

Will, why not use the Oracle parser?

```
create global temporary table plans as select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor());
--/
declare
c number;
i varchar2(30);
l number;
stmt varchar2(4000);
begin
delete from plans;
stmt:= 'select z.* from z,skew1 where z.z = skew1.fillblocks';
l:= length(stmt);
c:=dbms_sql.open_cursor();
dbms_sql.parse (c, stmt,dbms_sql.native);
select distinct sql_id into i from v$open_cursor where sid in (select sid from v$mystat) and substr(sql_text,1,l) = substr(stmt,1,l);
insert into plans select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(i));
dbms_output.put_Line ('sql_id:'||i);
end;
/
select * from plans;

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                             
----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
SQL_ID  97qc3ynmw1pa4, child number 0                                         
-------------------------------------                                         
select z.* from z,skew1 where z.z = skew1.fillblocks                          

Plan hash value: 942457544                                                    

----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
| Id  | Operation          | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |       |       |       |    85 (100)|          |  
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN         |       |     1 |   410 |    85   (2)| 00:00:02 |  
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| Z     |     1 |     9 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |  
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| SKEW1 |  6000 |  2349K|    82   (0)| 00:00:01 |  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------  

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                           
---------------------------------------------------                           

   1 - access("Z"."Z"=INTERNAL_FUNCTION("SKEW1"."FILLBLOCKS"))
```

You do need an oracle database connection. If the output is what you want, it is the easiest way to get what you want, without re-inventing an other color for a wheel. In this example I limited the sql to 4000 characters but you could feed a pl/sql array of varchar2 into to dbms_sql.parse function, doing so allows you to parse sql's of unimaginable sizes.

Comment: I actually only have the sql statement and nothing else. So I'm really restricted to statically analyze the SQL. Questions I need to answer include, what tables are in that sql statement.

Answer (score 4):

Given that Oracle Corporation couldn't keep the SQL parser for the SQL and PL/SQL VM's in sync when the two had different SQL parsers, it's unlikely that a third party would be able to create a "fully compliant" parser.

What data are you trying to extract from the query?  The Oracle database itself may have other facilities that would allow you to extract that information without parsing the query first.

Comment: I don't need to parse PL/SQL and I am restricted to the sql statements only (without access to a database).

Comment: I'm not talking about a PL/SQL parser.  Oracle has separate PL/SQL and SQL VM's internally.  For many years, they each had their own SQL parser.  And for many years, you'd find that you couldn't embed a particular valid SQL statement in a PL/SQL block because the PL/SQL VM's SQL parser couldn't parse it.  But when you passed that same SQL statement to the SQL VM, the SQL VM's SQL parser had no problem with it.  That's not a problem any longer because the two VM's share a single SQL parser.  But it does show the difficulty of keeping up with the evolution of the SQL grammar.

Comment: Thanks for the info.That's why I was saying that I only need a SQL parser. The problem that they couldn't keep their two different parsers in sync, does not affect the feasibilty for a third party to create a parser that can handle all the SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) can be obtained with an Oracle PLSQL parser, or a SQL 2011 parser.  DMS provides a parser, builds an AST, lets you investigate/transform the tree arbitrarily, and regenerate the AST as source code if you want to do that.

You can test out the parser by downloading the PLSQL formatter available from the website; that uses the same underlying DMS machinery; just doesn't analyze/transform the tree.

You might need to wrap the SQL statements in a simple PLSQL procedure.

Comment: Flagger: You could have the courtesy to explain why you dinged this answer. It directly answers OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://www.ibrezina.net/OracleSQL.tgz. It's ANTLR3.3 grammar for Oracle's PL/SQL. The grammar is intended for C target but can be easily converted into Java or C#. Your task, list of tables included in a query is already included as an example.

Comment: I wouldn't exactly say its easy to convert it into C#. At least not for a C# programmer.

Answer (score 1):

[jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org) has a built-in [parser](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/) that can parse a lot of the SQL by any of its supported database products, including Oracle SQL. It can't parse *all* of it, but it may be enough for most use-cases. For example, it can parse the Oracle outer join operator `(+)` and even [transform that to ANSI SQL](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/sql-transformation/table-lists-to-ansi-join/). [A parser and translator demo can be seen here](https://www.jooq.org/translate/), for example:

```sql
-- Input
SELECT *
FROM t, u
WHERE t.id = u.id(+)

-- Output
SELECT *
FROM t
  LEFT OUTER JOIN u
    ON t.id = u.id
```

You can use the parser from the [website](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/sql-transformation/table-lists-to-ansi-join/), [as a CLI](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/sql-parser-cli/), or programmatically using Java, Kotlin, Scala, etc:

```java
Select<?> select = ctx.parser().parseSelect(
    """
    SELECT *
    FROM t, u
    WHERE t.id = u.id(+)
    """
);
```

The parse output is ordinary jOOQ API, which you can transform to other SQL using jOOQ's [model API](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/model-api/)

Answer (score 0):

FlowHigh ships with an SQL parser that supports the Oracle SQL dialect including non ANSI joins.
You can use the UI or access it programmatically for automation using the Python SDK.

As input you give it an SQL statement and as output it generates a JSON or XML message.

The SDK also ships with a bunch of abstractions to satisfy common use cases, e.g. give me all the tables, joins, columns, filters etc. in a query

It can be used for static code analysis to detect bad SQL and SQL anti patterns such as self joins, SELECT * etc.

Here is a Medium blog post that describes it in more detail https://medium.com/@sonradata/parsing-oracle-sql-with-flowhigh-e366dae23920

Disclaimer: I work for Sonra