# PL/SQL source code parser (in Java)

Tags: java, parsing, plsql, analyzer

I'm looking for general purpose source parser in Java.
Library which can help me to parser PL/SQL code. Extract functions, procedures, packages and show dependencies between them.

Comment: You need more than a parser to compute "dependencies".  See my essay on Life After Parsing (www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html).

Answer (score 2):

Consider looking at [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) tool. There exist already [PL/SQL](http://antlr.org/grammar/1279318813752/PLSQL.g) grammar. Please spend some time for reading about this tool. It should surely solve your problem.

Comment: "Surely"?  PL/SQL is a *huge* language.  Don't expect this grammar to be complete.  Do expect real code to contain every bit of the language.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [plsql-parser](https://github.com/porcelli/plsql-parser) on GitHub, quote:

*This is a [almost] full parser for PL/SQL language that includes a Lexer, Parser (that optionally generates an Abstract Syntax Tree) and a TreeWalker. Current version is target for Java language, but may be easy to port it to any other target.*

I am interested in porting PL/SQL data structures to Java and will try it the next weeks.

Another option could be https://stackoverflow.com/a/6631453/734687, but note that you have to port the target language from C to Java.