# Oracle Scripts parsing using regex

Tags: java, regex, oracle, plsql

I am trying to parse the oracle scripts. The purpose is to extract the number of functions, procedures, Loops, Exceptions etc. What is the most suitable way to accomplish this? I am currently doing this with regex. But it seems that it is not covering all the scenarios. I need some alternative for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a following regex expression to find out the Packages, functions, procedures, loops, exceptions, metadata definitions, and anonymous blocks.

```
"create\\s+(or\\s+replace\\s+)?(package)\\s+(body\\s+)?([\\w\\.]+)" +//1-4
        "|(\\bcreate\\s+)?(\\bor\\s+)?(\\breplace\\s+)?(\\bfunction|\\bprocedure)\\s+(\\w+)" +//5-9
        "|(\\bexception)\\s" +//10
        "|(\\bcursor)\\s*(\\w+)"+//11-12
        "|(\\bloop)\\s"+//13
        "|(\\w+)\\s*([\\w\\.]+)\\s*%(ROW)?(TYPE);"+//14-17
        "|(\\bdeclare)\\s"//18
```

The technique is to eliminate the comments, and string literals and then apply the regex. It is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Its an interesting topic to do , you can use different purser . One popular one is [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).[Grammar](http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/1279318813752/PLSQL.g) for pl/sql is defined there.

You can also take a look [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985482/pl-sql-source-code-parser-in-java)

Comment: That's a nice suggestion but we are already using ANTLR for the SQL transformation. It is just for analysis purpose and we just need to have count of the functions, procedures, loops, exceptions etc.

Comment: ic , then if you people any other good alternative please share then , i am working in a project which has a lot of pl/sql script , some scripts are more then 7000 lines , if we can do so..then it will be helpful to document the code