# Differentiate .sql file whether it is PL/SQL or TSQL

Tags: c#, t-sql, plsql

I have a list of (.sql) files and some files are Oracle PL/SQL and others are Microsoft TSQL files. How can I differentiate whether the given .sql file is PL/SQL or TSQL using C#.net. How can we identify it.

I need some sample C# code to identify the type of file in a better way.

Is there any tools available to identify? Please guide me.

Regards,
Sivaprakash.

Comment: A simple `select` statement is the same in the 2 languages, so how would you like to differentiate them? My best approach would be to check if some specific PL/SQL words are present in the file and if that's the case, the file is a PL/SQL file, otherwise a TSQL file.

Comment: But putting them in different folders in the first place is not a good idea?

Comment: I need to create a parser tool, it should accept all .sql files and I need to differentiate if it and based on that I need to use parser type.

Comment: And how do you distinguish _SELECT * FROM TABLE_

Comment: I am using Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.Sql. (TSql100Parser) class to parse .sql file. In this case the parse will not throw any error.

Comment: It will treat it as a TSQL file.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your SQL Server version you could use a derivative of the Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.Sql.TSqlParser class to attempt to parse the SQL. Then you can examine the errors it produces (if any) to determine whether it is TSQL or not.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.schema.scriptdom.sql.tsqlparser(v=vs.100).aspx

This answer might help parsing PL/SQL

[Parser for Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735791/parser-for-oracle-sql)

Comment: I am using Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.Sql. (TSql100Parser)  class to parse the TSQL file. If the .sql file size increases, it takes more time to parse. For example, 2 MB file takes more than 8 mins to parse. It is not a best practice. Help me out.

Comment: You might want to update your question then. A hack might be to check for the presence of the GO keyword which is TSQL specific

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will check this.