# Easy way to port SQLs using decode to use case-when

Tags: sql, oracle, porting

I have hundreds of files containing SQLs that use Oracle's built-in function `decode`.  I want to port them to use `case-when` instead. Is there a program or set of programs that can automatically do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no such completed solution. You have to do *some* (read big) work for this task. You should do some parsing, choose one of the ways

1. Take full *Oracle SQL* parser and process AST in your own way then flush patched AST to a file (for example try to look here for parsers [Parser for Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735791/parser-for-oracle-sql) ).
2. Write your own parser sufficient (i mean a smaller subset of Oracle SQL language) for handling decode (This would be hard i guess, because decode can appear in many places\levels of the grammar and you have to implement alot). Tools for you here are lex+yacc, ANTLR etc.

Answer (score -2):

I don't recall anything that will port your Decode statements to case-when .
Why do you even want to do that , unless it's mandatory for you.
Decode is much more sophisticated and provides readable code even when the number of conditions increases.

Comment: I beg to differ. `case .. when` is **much** more sophisticated. How do you translate `case when some_column like 'Foo%' then other_column * 12 when id = 42 then other_column * 42 when purchase_date = trunc(current_date) then 0 end` to a decode statement?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , well the same can be achieved with multiple decode statements. like ,
decode(some_column,'foo%',other_col *12,0)
decode(some_col,'12',other+7,0)
Agreed ,decode will decode only one column at a time ,but still it looks more readable from programming point of view ,rather than inserting all those conditions in a single case-when. 
<Other lang reference>
Same goes with other languages as well, like in C/C++ , instead of specifying multiple conditions within a single if(, , , , , , , ,) block , it's better to use nested if else.

Comment: How do you use `LIKE` in a decode statement? Or `>`? Or `between`? Or `regexp_like`?

Comment: Well then you just cannot generalise everything. I'll agree on one point ,depending upon the requirement both case -when and decode have their pros and cons.

Comment: Obviously for relational operators you've got to use case when, but than again ,i was referring to his request. Not like he mentioned what his Decode statements comprised of.Just stated a point that decode is more readable and sophisticated. I never said Decode can 'totally' take over case-when.

Comment: Well you said "*decode is much more **sophisticated***" which simply isn't true.

Comment: may be chry want to execute those queries on a different platform like sql server which does not support decode, and that's why its required for him to convert decode into case.

Comment: You think what you think is always right, trying to impose your thoughts on others, well i beg to differ , unless Chry himself mentions about it in his questions,so go ahead post your answers,i'll vote up for you.

Comment: You even forgot to mention , how case expects datatype consistency but decode doesn't. Case often gives you datatype mismatch error but decode doesn't.

Comment: And i presented my view based on what i thought ,just because you think he wants to execute it on a different platform ,doesn't mean he actually does.