# Get table names and column names from SQL query String

Tags: java, sql, string, oracle11g

I am reading a CSV file into my java program and it has an sql query in its every record. I want to parse this (Select)SQL query to find the table names and column names mentioned in those queries.

e.g. Select age,name from Employee

*Result:*

*---- Tables:  [Employee]*

*---- Columns: [age,name]*

**NOTE: I do not want to fire the queries else I would have used ResultSetMetaData**

Comment: In its most general form, this will be a nightmare. Imagine selecting columns created in a PIVOT or a MATCH_RECOGNIZE clause... Expressions involving columns (analytic functions, aggregates, col1 + col2)...  What do you need this for?

Comment: may be you can try JSqlParser: https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser

Comment: You need to use any available oracle sql parser, tokenize input and get desired result using parser library. See if this thread helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735791/parser-for-oracle-sql

Comment: You may use DBMS_SQL.describe_columns

Answer (score 0):

For simple SQL statements like your example above i would use some simple string methods to get the info. Example:

```
public static void main (String[]args) { 
    String sql = "Select age,name,adress,id from Employee where id = 3";
    String[] columns = sql.substring(sql.indexOf("Select")+7, sql.indexOf("from")-1).split(",");
    String table = sql.substring(sql.indexOf("from")+5).split(" ")[0];
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(columns));
    System.out.println(table);
}
```