# SQL REGEX search for table name

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

this is my first entry, so please excuse me for any mistakes I might make writing this Post.

I have an oracle database schema full of Table Views. I want to use the "TEXT_VC" column in the "all_views" table to get a list of the source table names.

This is my statement so far:

```
SELECT view_name, text_vc, REGEXP_SUBSTR(TEXT_VC,'from (.+?) ') AS source_table 
FROM all_views 
WHERE owner = 'OWNER';
```

I still have a view problems with this regex. 
First of all, I am getting "from table_name" as a result. I don't want to get "from" in my result set.

Secondly, the column TEXT_VC basically displays the SQL behind the view. So in some cases I don't get any results, because there are line breaks. I tried working with \n and \r but I am not able to generate the result I want.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: I don't believe rexec can help generally. Consider `select from( select from... )` view. You may need  a parser  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735791/parser-for-oracle-sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from all_dependencies
```

#### Demo

```
create table mytable_1 (i int);
create table mytable_2 (i int);

create view myview 
as 
select  count(*) as cnt
from          mytable_1 t1 
        join  mytable_2 t2 
        on    t2.i = t1.i
;
```

---

```
select    * 
from      all_dependencies
where     owner = 'DMARKOVITZ'
      and name  = 'MYVIEW'
;
```

---

```
+------------+--------+------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------+
|   OWNER    |  NAME  | TYPE | REFERENCED_OWNER | REFERENCED_NAME | REFERENCED_TYPE | REFERENCED_LINK_NAME | DEPENDENCY_TYPE |
+------------+--------+------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------+
| DMARKOVITZ | MYVIEW | VIEW | DMARKOVITZ       | MYTABLE_1       | TABLE           | (null)               | HARD            |
| DMARKOVITZ | MYVIEW | VIEW | DMARKOVITZ       | MYTABLE_2       | TABLE           | (null)               | HARD            |
+------------+--------+------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution is even better than my attempt. I was able to go way back to the source tables, using your solution with a recursive sql.  `SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT *
          FROM DBA_DEPENDENCIES
         START WITH OWNER = 'SCHEMA_OWNER'
                AND REFERENCED_TYPE = 'VIEW'
        CONNECT BY OWNER = PRIOR REFERENCED_OWNER
               AND NAME = PRIOR REFERENCED_NAME
               AND TYPE = PRIOR REFERENCED_TYPE
               AND TYPE = 'VIEW')
 WHERE REFERENCED_TYPE <> 'VIEW';`